# Hermite Functions and Multiplication Operators: Why is the "obvious" equation correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

**Question:**  Let $T$ be the unbounded operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$Tf(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( x f(x) - f^{\prime}(x) \right), $$
with domain $\mathfrak{D}(T)$ restricted to the set where $xf(x)$ and $f^{\prime}(x)$ are each, separately, in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (and we permit $f^{\prime}(x)$ to be a distributional derivative).

It is known (e.g., Folland's *Real Analysis*, Exercise 8.23 (a -- c)) that $T h_k(x) = \sqrt{k + 1} h_{k + 1}(x)$, where $h_k(x)$ is the $k$th Hermite function (precise definition below).

Of course, the Hermite functions form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so for any $f \in \mathfrak{D}(T)$, we may write
$$f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} c_k h_k(x).$$

I would *like* to write then that for any $f \in \mathfrak{D}(T)$,

$$Tf(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} c_k T h_k(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} c_k \sqrt{k + 1} h_{k + 1}(x);$$
certainly, this would be true for *finite* sums.

> How do I justify the linearity across the *infinite* sum?

---

**Motivation:**  Let the (physicist's) Hermite functions be defined by
$$h_k(x) = \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi} 2^k k!}} e^{x^2/2} \left( \frac{d}{dx} \right)^k e^{-x^2}, \quad k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace;$$
they form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

We define $\ell^2$ to be the space of square-summable sequences, where we let the sequences be indexed starting at $0$ for convenience.  Then by $h_k(x)$ an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we know that the map $\iota: \ell^2 \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
\begin{equation}
\iota \left( (c_k)_{k = 0}^{\infty} \right) := \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} c_k h_k(x)
\end{equation}
is an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces.

I wish to relate conditions on the decay of the coefficients to the integrability of the resulting functions.  Let
$$\mathfrak{L}_1 = \left\lbrace (c_k)_{k = 0}^{\infty} \in \ell^2: (\sqrt{k + 1} c_k)_{k = 0}^{\infty} \in \ell^2 \right\rbrace$$
and 
$$\mathfrak{D}_1 = \left\lbrace f(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}): xf(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}), s \widehat{f}(s) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \right\rbrace,$$
where $\widehat{f}(s)$ is the Fourier transform of $f$, under the convention
\begin{equation} 
\widehat{f}(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{- i \pi x \cdot s} \, dx, \quad f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation}

I wish to show that $\iota (\mathfrak{L}_1) = \mathfrak{D}_1$.

---

I can handle the inclusion $\iota (\mathfrak{L}_1) \subseteq \mathfrak{D}_1$. We know that
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
x h_k(x) = \sqrt{\frac{k + 1}{2}} h_{k + 1}(x) + \sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}h_{k-1}(x),
\end{equation}
so again, for finite linear combinations of Hermite functions there is no issue.  Moreover, for any $(c_k) \in \mathfrak{L}_1$, let $f = \iota (c_k)$, and let $P_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\text{span} \langle h_0, h_1, \dotsc , h_n \rangle$.

By (1), for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P_n f$ is in the domain of the multiplication-by-$x$ operator, hereafter denoted $M_x$.  Moreover, we discern the loose bound that for $m \leq n$, $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ \Vert M_x P_n f - M_x P_m f \Vert_{L^2}^2 \leq 2 \sum_{k = m - 1}^{n + 1} (k + 1) \vert c_k \vert^2, $$
so by $f = \iota(c_k)$ and $( \sqrt{k + 1} c_k) \in \ell^2$, we see that the sequence $( M_x P_n f)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, hence convergent.  Obviously $P_n f \to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and $M_x P_n f \to g$ for some $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$; by closedness of $M_x$, we have that $f$ is in the domain of $M_x$ and $M_x f = \lim_{n \to \infty} M_x P_n f$.  In other words, $x f(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

By our convention on the Fourier transform, we have that (e.g., Folland, *Real Analysis*, Exercise 23h) that
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
\widehat{h}_k(s) = (-i)^k h_k(s);
\end{equation}
Hence, showing $s \widehat{f}(s) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ follows in essentially the same way.

---

In my attempt to show $\mathfrak{D}_1 \subseteq \iota(\mathfrak{L}_1)$, I note first that for all $f \in \mathfrak{D}_1$, $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $s \widehat{f}(s) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $f \in \mathcal{H}^1(\mathbb{R})$, the $L^2$-Sobolev space of first order, so in particular, the distributional derivative $f^{\prime}(x)$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Since for $f \in \mathfrak{D}_1$, we also have that $x f(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we see that $f \in \mathfrak{D}(T)$.  If the linearity holds, then by $Tf \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, it will follow that $(\sqrt{k + 1} c_k) \in \ell^2$, and we will be done.

Perhaps (probably!) it is just a mental block, but I am not as certain how the infinite limit holds in this direction.  Certainly
$$ \langle T h_j, T h_k \rangle = (k + 1) \delta_{j, k}, $$
so we have some orthogonality to work with, but I do not see the passage to infinite sums, even under the hypothesis that $f \in \mathfrak{D}(T)$.

Comment: Without the assumption $f\in D(T)$ the claim is false. In that case, nobody guarantees that $\sum \lvert c_k\rvert^2 (k+1)<\infty$, and so the infinite sums need not make sense at all. On the other hand, it is a theorem of operator theory that the condition $f\in D(T)$ is equivalent to $\sum \lvert c_k\rvert^2\lvert \lambda_k\rvert^2<\infty$, where the $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ (assumed, of course, that $T$ only has point spectrum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $Hf = -\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}f+x^{2}f$ is selfadjoint when defined on the domain $\mathcal{D}(H)$ consisting of all twice absolutely continuous functions $f$ for which $f,Hf \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. That is certainly far from obvious but, nevertheless, is true. In particular that means
$$
                    (Hf,g)=(f,Hg),\;\;\; f, g \in \mathcal{D}(H).
$$
The part that is even more interesting is that every $f \in \mathcal{D}(H)$ is such that $xf \in L^{2}$ and $f' \in L^{2}$, which allows the classical raising and lowering operators $L_{+}f=-f'+xf$ and $L_{-}f=f'+xf$ to be defined as valid Hilbert space operators on $\mathcal{D}(H)$. These operators are related to $H$ and *almost* give a factoring of $H$:
\begin{align}
             L_{+}L_{-} & =-(f'+xf)'+x(f'+xf) \\
      & =-f''-xf'-f+xf'+x^{2}f \\
      & =(H-I)f \\
        L_{-}L_{+} & = (-f'+xf)'+x(-f'+xf) \\
      & = -f''+xf'+f-xf'+x^{2}f \\
      & = (H+I)f.
\end{align}
Both $L_{+}$ and $L_{-}$ are well-defined on $\mathcal{D}(H)$ because of the properties give above. That makes these methods very sound Mathematically. Furthermore, it can be shown that the integration by parts terms vanish to give you
$$
          (Hf,g) = (f',g')+(xf',xg'),\;\;\; f,g\in\mathcal{D}(H).
$$
That tells you right away that the spectrum of $H$ is real and positive because $Hf=\lambda f$ gives
$$
         \lambda\|f\|^{2}=(Hf,f)=\|f'\|^{2}+\|xf\|^{2}.
$$
Therefore, if there is an $L^{2}$ eigenvector $f$, there is at least one $f_0$ with a minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_0 > 0$. That has an interesting consequence because of the raising and lowering operators. If there is such an $f_0$, then it is okay to apply any number of powers of $L_{+}$, $L_{-1}$ to $f_0$ because of the above discussion, and the result will also be in the domain of $H$. However,
\begin{align}
         HL_{-}f_0 & =  (L_{-}L_{+}-I)L_{-}f_0 \\
            & = L_{-}(L_{+}L_{-}-I)f_0 \\
            & = L_{-}((H-I)-I)f_0 \\
            & = (\lambda-2)L_{-}f_0
\end{align}
That's a problem because $L_{-}f_0$ becomes an eigenfunction with a lower eigenvalue. So you're left with the conclusion that the only way out of this trap is $L_{-}f_0=0$. That allows you to solve for $f_0$:
$$
              L_{-}f_0=f_0'+xf_0 = 0 \implies f_0 = Ce^{-x^{2}/2}.
$$
Automatically, from $L_{+}L_{-}+I=H$ and $L_{-}f_0=0$, you get the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda_{0}=1$:
$$
             Hf_{0} = (L_{+}L_{-}+I)f_{0}=f_{0}
$$
You can similarly show that $L_{+}f_0$ is an eigenfunction with a higher eigenvalue:
$$
            HL_{+}f_0 = (L_{+}L_{-}+I)L_{+}f_0 \\
              = L_{+}(L_{-}L_{+}+I)f_0 \\
              = L_{+}(H+2I)f_0 \\
              = (\lambda_0+2)L_{+}f_0
$$
That is, $L_{+}f_0$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_0+2$. And you can continue this problems to get a chain of eigenvectors $f_n=L_{+}^{n-1}f_0$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_0+2n$. And,
$$
        f_n = \left(-\frac{d}{dx}+x\right)^{n}f_0
$$
Using an integrating factor, you can write
$$
          (-\frac{d}{dx}+x)g = -e^{x^{2}/2}\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x^{2}/2}g)
$$
That's how you get
$$
                f_n = (-1)^{n}e^{x^{2}/2}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(e^{-x^{2}/2}f_0) \\
     = (-1)^{n}e^{x^{2}/2}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}e^{-x^{2}}.
$$
Then you just need normalization constants $C_n$ so that get an orthonormal set $\{ C_n f_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ of eigenfunctions:
$$
                       \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|C_nf_n|^{2}dx = 1.
$$
There is no continuous spectrum, and you know there cannot be any other eigenfunctions. So this must form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. That means every $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as the $L^{2}$ convergent sum
$$
               f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(f,C_nf_n)C_n f_n
$$
The ladder operators $L_{+}$ and $L_{-}$ map $\mathcal{D}(H)$ into $L^{2}$, as mentioned before. And you can show that $(L_{+}f,g)=(f,L_{-}g)$ for $f,g\in \mathcal{D}(H)$ using integration by parts. That allows you to expand
\begin{align}
                L_{+}f & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(L_{+}f,C_nf_n)C_nf_n \\
      & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(f,C_nL_{-}f_n))C_nf_n \\
      & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(f,C_n f_{n-1})C_n f_n
\end{align}
This sum is guaranteed to converge in $L^{2}$. You can do the same with $L_{-}$ as well. Then everything comes down to getting the constants right, such as writing $C_n f_{n-1}=\frac{C_n}{C_{n-1}}C_{n-1}f_{n-1}$. The integration by parts terms disappear because $f$, $f'$ are in $L^{2}$.

Comment: Good show.  One tiny typo:  In the last display equation, you forgot to move $L_+$ to $L_-$ when you moved to the other side.  It works out OK (you get $L_+ f = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_{n-1} \sqrt{n} h_n$, or adjusting the index by $1$, $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} c_k \sqrt{k + 1} h_{k + 1}$, as required), where $c_k = (f, h_k)$.

Comment: @user52733 : Slipped a gear. Thank you. I fixed that now.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'll accept.  I wanted to wait two days to see what other solutions came in.

Comment: @user52733 : You're probably not going to find much of a discussion about this topic. Have you been able to locate any references?